# What's the difference between insertDocuments vs importDocuments on ArangoCollection?

Tags: java, arangodb

I'm using ArangoDB java API to create my Java connector to ArangoDB.
On the official JavaDoc, I found that the ArangoCollection class has two methods insertDocuments and importDocuments, but I didn't find enough documentation to fully understand the differences.
Does someone have the answer?

Comment: Hi! can be possible that you typed twice the method ***importDocuments*** ??? maybe they are overload, java methods can have the same name but diff parameters, are you aware of that?

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, I fixed the question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the assumption you mean `insertDocuments` vs `importDocuments`:

- `insertDocuments` uses the HTTP [document api](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/HTTP/Document/WorkingWithDocuments.html#create-document)
- `importDocuments` uses the HTTP [import api](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/HTTP/BulkImports/#imports-document-values)

The method `insertDocuments` works the same as `insertDocument` but with a list of documents (i.e. Java Beans) and not only with a single document.

The method `importDocuments` allows additional options like a rule how to handle duplicate documents and also returns you details of the import: How many documents are imported or ignored and it provides details of every single document import.

The java driver provides two `importDocuments` method with different parameters:
`importDocuments(Collection)` and `importDocuments(String)`

- `importDocuments(Collection)` gets a list of objects
- `importDocuments(String)` gets a JSON-encoded array of objects